# Using multiple Swup plugins

Tags: transition, swup

I am using the Swup library to implement page transitions which is working great but I need to use 2 plugins (Scripts and Body Class).  I must be missing something because I cannot get both to work, only the last called works.  Is there a way to have more than 1 plugin with Swup?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what was your code to include multiple plugins?

You have to use something like:

```
const options = {
    plugins: [
        new SwupScriptsPlugin(),
        new SwupBodyClassPlugin()
    ],
 };
const swup = new Swup(options);
```